# Webpack Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token <

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I use webpack to bundle my js files,

Firstly when i run command `webpack` using npm on cmd then 2 bundle files are created namely `bundle.js` and `1.bundle.js`. Is it normal that 2 bundle files gets created??

Secondly when i use `bundle.js` in my `index.html` then it gets loaded and `1.bundle.js` also gets loaded on the page but `1.bundle.js` gets modified to like an html file with various scripts tags. Is that normal too??

Thirdly it shows an error in the console that that `Uncaugh syntax error: Unexpected token <` in the file `1.bundle.js` i.e when it reads `1.bundle.js` then it start reading `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` contained at the beginning of the file and shows an error that `<` in `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is unexpected. Any help would be super highly appreciated

`bundle.js`

```
    /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
    /******/    // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
    /******/    var parentJsonpFunction = window["webpackJsonp"];
    /******/    window["webpackJsonp"] = function webpackJsonpCallback(chunkIds, moreModules) {
    /******/        // add "moreModules" to the modules object,
    /******/        // then flag all "chunkIds" as loaded and fire callback
    /******/        var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, callbacks = [];
    /******/        for(;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
    /******/            chunkId = chunkIds[i];
    /******/            if(installedChunks[chunkId])
    /******/                callbacks.push.apply(callbacks, installedChunks[chunkId]);
    /******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
    /******/        }
    /******/        for(moduleId in moreModules) {
    /******/            modules[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
    /******/        }
    /******/        if(parentJsonpFunction) parentJsonpFunction(chunkIds, moreModules);
    /******/        while(callbacks.length)
    /******/            callbacks.shift().call(null, __webpack_require__);

    /******/    };

    /******/    // The module cache
    /******/    var installedModules = {};

    /******/    // object to store loaded and loading chunks
    /******/    // "0" means "already loaded"
    /******/    // Array means "loading", array contains callbacks
    /******/    var installedChunks = {
    /******/        0:0
    /******/    };

    /******/    // The require function
    /******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

    /******/        // Check if module is in cache
    /******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
    /******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

    /******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    /******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
    /******/            exports: {},
    /******/            id: moduleId,
    /******/            loaded: false
    /******/        };

    /******/        // Execute the module function
    /******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

    /******/        // Flag the module as loaded
    /******/        module.loaded = true;

    /******/        // Return the exports of the module
    /******/        return module.exports;
    /******/    }

    /******/    // This file contains only the entry chunk.
    /******/    // The chunk loading function for additional chunks
    /******/    __webpack_require__.e = function requireEnsure(chunkId, callback) {
    /******/        // "0" is the signal for "already loaded"
    /******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] === 0)
    /******/            return callback.call(null, __webpack_require__);

    /******/            script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + ".bundle.js";
    /******/            head.appendChild(script);
    /******/        }
    /******/    };

    /******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
    /******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

    /******/    // expose the module cache
    /******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

    /******/    // __webpack_public_path__
    /******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

    /******/    // Load entry module and return exports
    /******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
    /******/ })
    /************************************************************************/
    /******/ ([
    /* 0 */
    /***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

        __webpack_require__.e/* require */(1, function(__webpack_require__) { var __WEBPACK_AMD_REQUIRE_ARRAY__ = [
          // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
          __webpack_require__(1),

        ]; (function(test){
          test.init();
        }.apply(null, __WEBPACK_AMD_REQUIRE_ARRAY__));});
        //saksham was here

    /***/ }
    /******/ ]);
```

`1.bundle..js`

```
webpackJsonp([1],[
    /* 0 */,
    /* 1 */
    /***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

        var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [
          __webpack_require__(3),
          __webpack_require__(20),
          __webpack_require__(14),
          __webpack_require__(15),
          __webpack_require__(16),
          __webpack_require__(17),
          __webpack_require__(6),
          __webpack_require__(11),
          __webpack_require__(29),
          __webpack_require__(32),
          __webpack_require__(33)

        ], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = function($, jPlayer, d_qtip_2, emotify, colorpicker, fileattachment){

          var init = function() {
            $(document).ready(function(){
              if(typeof(window.xxxx)==="function") {
                window.xxxx();
                console.log("saksham is a virus");
              }
              xxx.xxxx();
              if(!(xxxx.checkMobile() && xxxx.embed.id === false && xxxx.app.mobile_web === '1')){
                xxxx.init();
                xxxx.init();
              }
              else{
                xxxx.emit('mobileButtonLoad', []);
              }

            });

            aaaa.on('ChatDisconnected', function() {
              if(xxxx.app.chatAccess) {
                xxxx.init();
              }
              else{
                $('#drupalchat-wrapper').hide();
                //console.log('hidden');
                //console.log(xxx.frontend.altrovr );
                if(xxx.frontend.altrovr == true){
                  $("#drupalchat-altrovr").show();
                  $("#drupalchat").hide();
                }
              }
            });
          };

          return {
            'init': init
          };


        }.apply(exports, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__), __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ !== undefined && (module.exports = __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__));

 ...etc
```

Now `1.bundle.js` gets modified to this. I copied it from networks section beside the console in the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
  xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://web.iflychatdev.com:12000/websites/t3/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link rel="shortlink" href="/websites/t3/node/1" />
<link rel="canonical" href="/websites/t3/node/1" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
  <title>iflychat-require-app | T3</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">

</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import 

...etc
```

Now is it normal?? that file gets changed

And how to get rid of that error of unexpected token <

p.s: I am migrating my app from requirejs to webpack

`webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //our config
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'require'),
  entry: './iflychat-main',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['.','./require/libs'],
  },
}
```

Comment: Please provide your webpack config.

Comment: added `webpack.config` file

Comment: `bundle.js` requested from `[site]/websites/t3/iflychat-app/require/bundle.js` and `1.bundle.js` from `[site]/websites/t3/node/1.bundle.js`, so, that file cant be found and those `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is just Drupal 404 page.

Comment: You need to specify `publicPath` in `output` section with value `/websites/t3/iflychat-app/require/`

Comment: You are the best buddy, you know I owe you a pizza. Its working now. Thanks for the help buddy. Maybe you can put it in an answer and i'll accept it. I was stuck on it for like 5hrs from now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main js file `bundle.js` trying to request chunks from url generated in this way:

```
script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + ".bundle.js";
```

where `__webpack_require__.p` is webpack public path.

That means chunks will load from path relative to document (`/websites/t3/node/`). But since your files are located in `/websites/t3/iflychat-app/require/`, chunks will not be loaded properly.

So, solution is specifying correct path to js assets:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    publicPath: '/websites/t3/iflychat-app/require/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  ...
}
```